# How to call objects in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I am kind of embarrassed about this, and definitely I am just forgetting something simple.

if this is body.java

```
public class body{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i = 0;
     part aPart = new part(i);
     aPart.add();
    }
}
```

and this is part.java

```
public class part{

    private int i;
    public int part(int i)
    {
        this.i = i+10;
    }
    public add ()
    {
        i = i++;
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Why when i run javac to compile body.java, it says unknown symbol for part?

Comment: Are these in the same package?

Comment: If you'd like something that will take care of compilation for you, and you want something simpler and lighter than Eclipse, check out http://www.drjava.org.

Comment: Always define the first character in a Java class in upper case (Body, Part)

Answer (score 4):

because part is your constructor (you don't declare the return type as @amir said in his answer).  You should do

```
public part(int i) {...}
```

as a note, Java convention is to have class names capitalized, so you should change your file to Part.java, your class declaration to "Part", and your constructor too...

EDIT -- @coolbeans answer is correct too -- if your code in the question is correct, you are missing a closing brace.

Comment: yes, i noticed the capitalization issue. I'm having the problem in a much bigger program, so i thought it better to try and make this test program to see what i forgot. I found the issue though, after comparing, I was making edits and made one too many!

Answer (score 1):

`javac *.java`?

Comment: That is the immediate problem... but the `part` constructor is also wrong

Answer (score 1):

Change your Part class like below:-

```
public class Part{

    private int i;
    public Part(int i)
    {
        this.i = i+10;
    }
    public void add()
    {
        i = i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

And call it this way:-

```
int i = 0;
Part aPart = new Part(i);
aPart.add();
```

Comment: thanks, that helped me find the problem in my bigger program i was editing.

Answer (score 0):

And to elaborate on what hvgotcodes said, constructors do not have a return type.  The constructor of a Java class is not an ordinary method. It's sole purpose is to instantiate an object of the the class which it belongs to.

Comment: i referenced your answer in my answer, if that is OK with you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the constructor

```
public part(int i) {
   this.i = i;
}
```